# Postgres: what's wrong with the syntax of this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a fairly straightforward PSQL query to retrieve some data (I realise it's not the most efficient query right now):

```
SELECT c.name AS article, c.id AS article_id, t.name AS template, t.id AS template_id, brand_names, COUNT(p.component_id)
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN components c 
(SELECT string_agg(b.name, ', ') AS brand_names 
 FROM brands b
 INNER JOIN brands_components 
 ON b.id = brands_components.brand_id
 WHERE brands_components.component_id = c.id
) brand_query
ON c.id = p.component_id 
INNER JOIN brands_components bc
ON c.id = bc.component_id
AND bc.brand_id IN (16, 23, 24, 35, 37)
INNER JOIN components_templates ct
ON c.id = ct.component_id
INNER JOIN templates t
ON t.id = ct.template_id
```

This gives me a syntax error though on line 4. What's missing? If I run the subquery alone it works fine:

> syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 4: (SELECT string_agg(b.name, ', ') AS brand_names ^ : SELECT c.name AS article, c.id AS article_id, t.name AS template, t.id AS template_id, brand_nam

The subquery is designed to retrieve all the brand names per component and display them in a single row instead of many. Their join table is `brands_components`.

A fiddle that is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8aef7/1), the desired result should be something like:

```
article         article_id   template       template_id   count   brands
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
component one | 1          | template one | 1           | 4     | brand one, brand two, brand three, brand four
```

Comment: Oh magic crystal ball, reveal to us this mysterious _"error"_ OP speaks of

Comment: Ha, sorry, updated.

Comment: So what usually comes after `JOIN something alias...`? Typically it's the keyword _"ON"_

Comment: What are you attempting to do with that in-line select right after your first INNER JOIN? That's your syntax error.

Comment: I think the error is here `INNER JOIN components c (SELECT string_agg(b.name, ', ') AS brand_names`

Comment: I think brand_names needs alies . like "brand_query.brand_names"

Comment: Try my Updated answer, Hope it helps

Comment: Use a lateral join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem could be solved with a a lateral join:

```
SELECT c.name AS article, c.id AS article_id, t.name AS template, t.id AS template_id, brand_names, COUNT(p.component_id)
FROM publications p
  JOIN components c ON c.id = p.component_id 
  JOIN brands_components bc ON c.id = bc.component_id AND bc.brand_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT b.id, string_agg(b.name, ', ') AS brand_names 
    FROM brands b
      JOIN brands_components ON b.id = brands_components.brand_id
    WHERE brands_components.component_id = c.id
    GROUP BY b.id
  ) brand_query ON brand_query.id = bc.brand_id
  JOIN components_templates ct ON c.id = ct.component_id
  JOIN templates t ON t.id = ct.template_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

The above would still not run because the `group by` doesn't include the `brand_names` column. Postgres doesn't know that `brand_names` is already aggregates.

However, the derived table is not really needed if you move the aggregation to the outer query:

```
SELECT c.name AS article, 
       c.id AS article_id, 
       t.name AS template, 
       t.id AS template_id, 
       string_agg(b.name, ',') as brand_names, 
       COUNT(p.component_id)
FROM publications p
  JOIN components c ON c.id = p.component_id 
  JOIN brands_components bc ON c.id = bc.component_id AND bc.brand_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  JOIN brands b on b.id = bc.brand_id
  JOIN components_templates ct ON c.id = ct.component_id
  JOIN templates t ON t.id = ct.template_id
GROUP BY c.name, c.id, t.name, t.id;
```

Comment: That's _miles_ more efficient and makes a lot more sense. Thank-you!

Comment: @CD-RUM: actually the intermediate step that left out the `brands` table in the sub-select was wrong ;)

Comment: Ha, gotcha. This seems to get a lot of duplicates in the `brand_name` results when it should be unique. Any way to address that too? Not that you haven't helped enough already...

Comment: @CD-RUM: you could simply use `string_agg(distinct b.name, ',')`

Comment: @CD-RUM: the "duplicates" stem from the joins as you get each brand and brand_component multiple times. The idea with the derived table to eliminate those duplicates wasn't that bad to begin with - for large tables that might actually be more efficient - however it's not that easy to integrate because of the different levels of aggregation that you need there

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense. Thanks so much for your help, I've got a clearer handle on all this now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT c.name AS article, c.id AS article_id, t.name AS template, t.id AS template_id,MAX(brand_names) AS brand_names, COUNT(p.component_id) AS Counts
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN components c 
ON c.id = p.component_id 
INNER JOIN brands_components bc
ON c.id = bc.component_id
AND bc.brand_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
INNER JOIN components_templates ct
ON c.id = ct.component_id
INNER JOIN templates t
ON t.id = ct.template_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT string_agg(b.name, ', ') AS brand_names 
 FROM brands b
 INNER JOIN brands_components bcc
 ON b.id = bcc.brand_id
 INNER JOIN components c ON bcc.component_id = c.id
) brand_query ON brand_names IS NOT NULL
Group by c.name,c.id,t.name,t.id
```

Comment: That returns this error: `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "c" LINE 12: WHERE brands_components.component_id = c.id ^ HINT: There is an entry for table "c", b`

Comment: That works! I also got it working myself, but I'll accept yours and post mine. I'm not sure what's more efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

I got it [working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8aef7/22) with a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION brands(int) RETURNS varchar AS $$
  SELECT string_agg(b.name, ', ') AS brand_names 
  FROM brands b
  INNER JOIN brands_components 
  ON b.id = brands_components.brand_id
  WHERE brands_components.component_id = $1
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT c.name, c.id, t.name AS template_name, t.id AS template_id, brands(c.id), COUNT(p.component_id)
FROM publications p
INNER JOIN components c 
ON c.id = p.component_id 
INNER JOIN brands_components bc
ON c.id = bc.component_id
AND bc.brand_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
INNER JOIN components_templates ct
ON c.id = ct.component_id
INNER JOIN templates t
ON t.id = ct.template_id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Not sure which is preferable, likely it's DineshDB's though.